# How to make javascript transitions not stop when I change tabs

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a carousel but I found the problem that every time I switch tabs and return, the animations are delayed, is there a way to solve this?

I tried to do something with the page visibility api but couldn't fix it, also try using requestAnimationFrame but it doesn't work either

[image: Image from Gyazo]

As you can see in the gif when I change the tab and come back the transition is delayed

My code:

```
"use strict";
class Carousel {
    constructor(_options) {
        this.images = [];
        this.imgIndex = 1;
        this.transitionStatus = null;
        this.options = {
            autoplay: {
                enabled: true,
                speed: 5000
            },
            speed: 5000
        };
        this.nextQueue = 0;
        //config options
        Object.assign(this.options, _options);
        //set props
        this.container = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel__container")[0];
        this.itemsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel__items")[0];
        //get imgs from carousel items and remove #text's childs
        document.querySelectorAll(".carousel__item").forEach(item => {
            item.childNodes.forEach((child) => child.nodeName === "IMG" ? this.images.push(child) : false);
        });
        this.setup();
    }
    setup() {

        //add class to all images in carouselContainer
        for (let index = 0; index < this.images.length; index++) {
            const image = this.images[index];
            image === null || image === void 0 ? void 0 : image.classList.add('carousel__itemImg'); /* img */
        }
        const toContainerFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

        // create span index image counter
        this.spanIndex = document.createElement('span');
        this.spanIndex.classList.add('container__number'); //imgIndex
        this.updateIndexContent();
        toContainerFragment.appendChild(this.spanIndex);

        //create next prev arrows
        const arrowNext = document.createElement("span");
        arrowNext.id = "carousel_next";
        arrowNext.textContent = "=>";
        toContainerFragment.appendChild(arrowNext);
        const arrowPrev = document.createElement("span");
        arrowPrev.id = "carousel_prev";
        arrowPrev.textContent = "<=";
        toContainerFragment.appendChild(arrowPrev);
        arrowNext.addEventListener("click", () => this.next());
        arrowPrev.addEventListener("click", () => this.prev());
        
        //add arrows and span index to container
        this.container.appendChild(toContainerFragment);
        //autoplay
        if (this.options.autoplay.enabled) {
            this.autoPlay();
        }
    }
next() {
    if (this.imgIndex == this.images.length) {
        this.imgIndex = 0;
    }
    if (this.transitionStatus == "started") {
        this.nextQueue++;
        return;
    }
    const clientWidth = this.container.clientWidth;
    this.imgIndex++;
    this.updateIndexContent();
    this.itemsContainer.style.transition = `transform ${this.options.speed}ms linear`;
    this.itemsContainer.style.transform = `translateX(-${clientWidth}px)`;
    this.transitionStatus = "started";
    const transitionEndEvent = () => {
        this.itemsContainer.removeEventListener("transitionend", transitionEndEvent);
        this.itemsContainer.style.transition = "none";
        this.itemsContainer.style.transform = `translateX(-${0}px)`;
        const previousElement = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel__item")[0];
        this.itemsContainer.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", previousElement);
        this.transitionStatus = "ended";
        if (this.nextQueue) {
            this.nextQueue--;
            this.next();
        }
    };
    this.itemsContainer.addEventListener("transitionend", transitionEndEvent);
}

    updateIndexContent() {
        this.spanIndex.textContent = `${this.imgIndex} / ${this.images.length}`;
    }

    autoPlay() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.next();
        }, this.options.autoplay.speed);
    }
}
const carousel = new Carousel({
    autoplay: {
        enabled: false,
        speed: 1000
    },
    speed: 5000
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="carousel__container">
      <div class="carousel__items">
        <div class="carousel__item">
          <img src="../assets/1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel__item">
          <img src="../assets/2.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel__item">
          <img src="../assets/3.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel__container{
  width: 90%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.carousel__items{
  display: flex;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel__item{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel__itemImg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#carousel_prev {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 15;
  left: 12%;
  top: 50%;
  color: blue;
}

#carousel_next {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 15;
  right: 12%;
  top: 50%;
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: The scrolling velocity on your carousel is too slow IMHO. If you delete the `visibilitychange` event handler, you can see that the carousel keeps scrolling in the hidden tab. Perhaps you're focusing on a feature that isn't interesting ?

Comment: If you insist, in that handler when focusing the tab you're not doing anything with the `resume` variable. You must update position with the cached value.

Comment: I already removed the visibility change (update post) and still have the same "error". As for your opinion it's true, the feature is pretty useless, but I can't leave it at that knowing that it can be done a little bit better xd. look I found this repository that has a similar code and the bug does not pass https://github.com/balboacodes/image-carousel-html-css-javascript is something that my code has but I don't realize that it is

Comment: https://codepen.io/balboacodes/pen/eYYmyJm change the transition speed and see that the bug does not appear

Comment: It seems really weird to me to have so much code for a simple linear carousel, when it can be done in a few lines of javascript and css for transitions. If you want I can make here a sample code

Comment: The problem is that in the future I want to make the transitions "dynamic" so I need them to be in the javascript and not in the css

Comment: Well, show me how you would do it. what I meant by dynamic is having a button and pressing it change the transition

Comment: I've done it.. some feedback ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can't. Browsers stop executing or throttle JS when a tab isn't active. It's all a battery and performance optimisation issue.

Answer (score 0):

here it is, (this just a modest  sample code)

```js
const
  myCarousel = document.querySelector('#carousel')   
, caro =
  { current : 0
  , count   : 4
  }
function movImg(direction)
  {
  caro.current = (caro.current + (caro.count + direction)) % caro.count
  myCarousel.style.setProperty('--posLeft', `-${300 *caro.current}px`)
  }
  
  /*
  == sample tool part for duration ==
  */
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]').forEach(r=>r.oninput=_=>
  {
  r.closest('label').dataset.val = r.value
  myCarousel.style.setProperty(`--${r.id}`, `${r.value}ms`)
  })
```

```css
#carousel {
  --duration : 300ms;
  --posLeft  : 0px;
  display    : block;
  position   : relative;
  margin     : auto;
  width      : 300px;
  height     : 300px;
  overflow   : hidden;
  }

#carousel > div {
  position       : absolute;
  display        : flex;
  flex-direction : row;
  flex-wrap      : nowrap;
  top            : 0;
  left           : var(--posLeft);
  transition     : var(--duration) ease-in-out;
  }
 

/*== sample tool part for duration ==*/
label.rg input {
  vertical-align : middle;
  width          : 300px;
  }
label.rg::after {
  content : attr(data-val) 'ms';
  }
label.rg::before {
  display : inline-block;
  width   : 4.5em;
  content : attr(data-lib);
  }
```

```html
<label class="rg" data-val="300" data-lib="duration"><input type="range" id="duration"  min="200" max="2000" step="100" value="300"></label>  
<br><br>
<button onclick="movImg(-1)">Left</button>
<button onclick="movImg(+1)">Right</button>
<hr>
 
<div id="carousel">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/300/300" >
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/300/300" >
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/300/300" >
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/240/300/300" >
  </div>
</div>
```